# controller vs viewmodel vs domain model Asp.net MVC best practices VS Wicket Framework MVC

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, wicket

I have been learning Asp.net MVC 4 and have a background in Wicket. I understand the MVC architecture from a design approach but reading the book "pro asp.net mvc 4 4th edition," there are some practices I am adjusting to.

One example (using entity framework) abstracts the domain away from the project entirely - creating a separate project for the domain model.

My interpretation of this is:

domain model = strictly objects to store a row of table data. Sanitation done here for input.

view model = any data passed to from controller to view

controller = processing information to send to the view

As you can see my understanding is pretty lightweight of each type because the view model vs domain model confuses me.

In the Wicket Framework it was model = business logic/database push and pulls, controller handled the logic of preparing to the data for presentation, and pushed it to the view, then the view is presentation/markup only code.

I am trying to get a grasp coming from the java/Wicket side of things how to understand the asp.net MVC best practices.

Comment: You need to differentiate MVC pattern vs. MVC framework. In MVC pattern M is data and business logic. In MVC framework it is C that more of a business logic because it is calling BLL and then wires data model with the view. In ASP.net MVC framework M is literally a model or viewmodel where you get data to generate your view. Controller is the one that calls your Domain objects to fill your Model and pass it to the view. Entity Framework is completely optional

Comment: Thanks, what does "BLL" refer to? And in MVC Framework the Business logic and data sanitizing is more commonly done in the Controller?

Comment: BLL is business Logic Layer. Do you mean, data validation? There can be few layers of validation. First is on UI. BLL can have validation. Then, your data model that is saved to your repository can have its own validation. We have Web API in which controllers don't do anything. They pass objects to a library, which does validation, authentication, etc. I wouldn't make controller to do much besides calling BLL and setting view with the model - for testability.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks T.S. That makes things more clearer working with MVC Framework.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net is similar to the Spring MVC in Java, or Struts2. so basically you have model object which is you data object, this data object will get filled by the controller for you different operation such as GET, POST, PUT, and Delete. then the controller is responsible to send these model to the view which will use the Razor to manipulate your syntax, so in this context Razor is some thing similar to JSTL in Java. So You cannot compare Wicket to ASP.net MVC because Wicket is widgets API in java similar to the standard ASP.net. Hopefully this give you better idea.